# Problemas com dados incorretos em um dataset (usando Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tenho um dataset chamado Auto.csv, que tem a forma:

```
mpg cylinders   displacement    horsepower  weight  acceleration    year    origin  name
18  8   307 130 3504    12  70  1   chevrolet chevelle malibu
15  8   350 165 3693    11.5    70  1   buick skylark 320
18  8   318 150 3436    11  70  1   plymouth satellite
16  8   304 150 3433    12  70  1   amc rebel sst
17  8   302 140 3449    10.5    70  1   ford torino
15  8   429 198 4341    10  70  1   ford galaxie 500
14  8   454 220 4354    9   70  1   chevrolet impala
14  8   440 215 4312    8.5 70  1   plymouth fury iii
14  8   455 225 4425    10  70  1   pontiac catalina
?   8   390 190 3850    8.5 70  1   amc ambassador dpl
15  8   383 170 3563    10  70  1   dodge challenger se
14  8   340 160 3609    8   70  1   plymouth 'cuda 340
15  8   400 150 3761    9.5 70  1   chevrolet monte carlo
14  8   455 225 3086    10  70  1   buick estate wagon (sw)
24  4   113 95  2372    15  70  3   toyota corona mark ii
22  6   198 95  2833    15.5    70  1   plymouth duster
18  6   199 97  2774    15.5    70  1   amc hornet
21  6   200 85  2587    16  70  1   ford maverick
```

Imagine que o dataset tem 1milhão de linhas e, possivelmente em algum lugar há um caracter no lugar de um número, ou seja, por um erro, em algum lugar na coluna `mpg` que deveria conter apenas números há uma caracter estranho como '?'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

carros = pd.read_csv('Auto.csv',sep =',')
print(carros['mpg'])
```

Como eu posso testar se a coluna `mpg` por exemplo, contém apenas números e, em caso, contrário, retornar um novo dataframe Pandas com a linha removida?

Fonte do dataset: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma segura para testar se o valor da linha é numérico (para os dados da pergunta), é definir uma função que tenta efetuar a conversão para `int` e verifica se houve erro:

```
def e_numero(x):
    try:
        # tenta converter para inteiro
        int(x)
        # retorna verdadeiro se conseguir...
        return True
    except ValueError:
        # ... ou falso, caso não consiga
        return False
```

Após definir a função, para testar se há linhas com valor incorreto na coluna:

```
dt[dt['mpg'].apply(lambda x: not(e_numero(x)))]
```

E para gerar o novo *DataFrame* sem as linhas incorretas:

```
dt_novo = dt[dt['mpg'].apply(lambda x: e_numero(x))]
```

Segue uma sessão de exemplo:

```
# Dados
dt
Out[54]:
   mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  year  origin                       name
0   18          8           307         130    3504          12.0    70       1  chevrolet chevelle malibu
1   15          8           350         165    3693          11.5    70       1          buick skylark 320
2   18          8           318         150    3436          11.0    70       1         plymouth satellite
3   16          8           304         150    3433          12.0    70       1              amc rebel sst
4   17          8           302         140    3449          10.5    70       1                ford torino
5   15          8           429         198    4341          10.0    70       1           ford galaxie 500
6   14          8           454         220    4354           9.0    70       1           chevrolet impala
7   14          8           440         215    4312           8.5    70       1          plymouth fury iii
8   14          8           455         225    4425          10.0    70       1           pontiac catalina
9    ?          8           390         190    3850           8.5    70       1         amc ambassador dpl
10  15          8           383         170    3563          10.0    70       1        dodge challenger se
11  14          8           340         160    3609           8.0    70       1         plymouth 'cuda 340
12  15          8           400         150    3761           9.5    70       1      chevrolet monte carlo
13  14          8           455         225    3086          10.0    70       1    buick estate wagon (sw)
14  24          4           113          95    2372          15.0    70       3      toyota corona mark ii
15  22          6           198          95    2833          15.5    70       1            plymouth duster
16  18          6           199          97    2774          15.5    70       1                 amc hornet
17  21          6           200          85    2587          16.0    70       1              ford maverick

# AQUI => Lista as linhas com valores não numéricos na coluna mpg
dt[dt['mpg'].apply(lambda x: not(e_numero(x)))]
Out[55]:
  mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  year  origin                name
9   ?          8           390         190    3850           8.5    70       1  amc ambassador dpl

# AQUI => Cria o DataFrame dt_novo sem as linhas com valores incorretos
dt_novo = dt[dt['mpg'].apply(lambda x: e_numero(x))]

dt_novo
Out[57]:
   mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  year  origin                       name
0   18          8           307         130    3504          12.0    70       1  chevrolet chevelle malibu
1   15          8           350         165    3693          11.5    70       1          buick skylark 320
2   18          8           318         150    3436          11.0    70       1         plymouth satellite
3   16          8           304         150    3433          12.0    70       1              amc rebel sst
4   17          8           302         140    3449          10.5    70       1                ford torino
5   15          8           429         198    4341          10.0    70       1           ford galaxie 500
6   14          8           454         220    4354           9.0    70       1           chevrolet impala
7   14          8           440         215    4312           8.5    70       1          plymouth fury iii
8   14          8           455         225    4425          10.0    70       1           pontiac catalina
10  15          8           383         170    3563          10.0    70       1        dodge challenger se
11  14          8           340         160    3609           8.0    70       1         plymouth 'cuda 340
12  15          8           400         150    3761           9.5    70       1      chevrolet monte carlo
13  14          8           455         225    3086          10.0    70       1    buick estate wagon (sw)
14  24          4           113          95    2372          15.0    70       3      toyota corona mark ii
15  22          6           198          95    2833          15.5    70       1            plymouth duster
16  18          6           199          97    2774          15.5    70       1                 amc hornet
17  21          6           200          85    2587          16.0    70       1              ford maverick
```

Comment: Testei o código   carros[carros['mpg'].apply(lambda x: not(e_numero(x)))]  mas não retornou nada!

Comment: Você testou com os dados da pergunta? Certeza que os dados tem uma linha inválida na coluna 'mpg'?